# Some bright backgrounds

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

All the edit boxes are still white, and combined with dark design this is really eye-hurting. I think they should all look like the search box.

BTW there are few issues of bright text on bright background in the moderator tools.

Comment: +1 agreed, e.g. right now I'm looking at the notification bar that pops up at the bottom of the page when I visit a post that somebody has flagged.

Comment: Also the "start a bounty" link is white on nearly-white.

Answer (score 2):

One example of this is the "share this hot question" box:[image]

That box near the mouse is supposed to say "to earn the publicist badge."

Comment: heh I just noticed your Chrome has "blackboard learn" as a linked site! :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery animation after answer is a white blast.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the bright input areas have been fixed, including the one mbq mentioned.

(Please try to open one item or *strongly* related item(s) per question, otherwise it's hard to process this stuff.)